# Qt lib to capture user's sound card output

Tags: qt, audio, capture, output

Is there any library in Qt to capture the audio output of the user's sound card ?
I'd like to find a portable way to do it (windows + mac).
If not, how could I achieve this for Windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows: WASAPI loopback capture
OS X: Sox + WavTap